# How to copy or transfer one bigquery dataset to another bigquery from a different gcp organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have some datasets in my own bigquery account (organization A) that needs to be transferred to another bigquery account in organization B. How to do it?

I am aware the data transfer service and RESTapi but that seem to be transfer data across project and region level within the organization.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use BigQuery [Copy Datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets) feature (beta feature at the moment) to copy datasets across projects/organization and across regions (not all regions supported). Cross organization copy works as long as you don't have VPC service controls set. You can use **COPY DATASET** or **TRANSFERS** on BQ Web UI or use CLI. Using Transfers allows running the copy on a recurring schedule.

Usage: `bq mk --transfer_config --project_id=[PROJECT_ID] --data_source=[DATA_SOURCE] --target_dataset=[DATASET] --display_name=[NAME] --params='[PARAMETERS]'`

Use `—params` for the specifying source dataset and other options.